# Add squiggles programmatically in Word

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-automation

How can I programmatically add Squiggle line under specific words in MS Word using C# Automation?
I guess I need to use the Range object, but I couldn't find and method / property that does that.

Is there any way of doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: You mean the one when words are spelt wrong?...

Comment: You can turn them off `ActiveDocument.ShowSpellingErrors = False` but apart from misspelling words I doubt there is a method available.